# Angular - Content Security Policy(CSP) support for inline style, eval etc

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

Angular official has no recommendation over the approach and support towards Content Security Policy. Has anyone has solution towards a strict CSP site with angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Meta class shipped with angular to add a Meta tag.

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  ....
 constructor(private meta: Meta) 
   ...
       meta.addTag({http-equiv: 'Content-Security-Policy', content: `default-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; ${moreFromVariable} `});
```